# Job failed: failed to pull image "node:latest" with specified policies [always]: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI in windows as base image.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0.202-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
..................................
app_build:
  stage: build
  only: 
    - Dev
  image: node:latest
  tags:
    - my-tag
  script:
    - |
      cd Receipt

      npm install

      npm run build --prod
```

> WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries (manager.go:237:1s)
> ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "node:latest" with specified policies [always]: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17763 in the manifest list entries (manager.go:237:1s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [NodeJS docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) only publishes Linux containers. There are no available images for Windows OS in any architecture.

You will have to either use a different image built for Windows or enable Linux container virtualization on your host (["switch to linux containers"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux#run-your-first-linux-container)) -- but keep in mind you won't be able to pull Windows images while the daemon is configured for Linux containers.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482494/5747944) for additional context.